# PIPESTATUS ignores negation?

Tags: bash, shell, negation, exitstatus, pipestatus

I just found the following results in bash (version 4.2.25(1)-release):

```
$ true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
$ ! true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
$ false; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1
$ ! false; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1
$ true && false; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1
$ true && ! false; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1
```

So, `$PIPESTATUS` seems to ignore negations in all cases.  Is this a known issue?  I couldn't find anything about it.  Or is this a wanted behavior?  If so, what's the reasoning behind it?

When using a subshell, everything works as I would have expected it:

```
$ (true && ! false); echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
```

Comment: Just a remark:  `$?` does not have this issue, it has the expected value (0 for `! false` etc.), so it is not part of this question.

Comment: `$?` >Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline. `$PIPESTATUS` > exit status values from the processes. Maybe it only counts the false/true true part as a process.

Comment: Yeah, appears so.  For a `! a | b | c | d` the `$PIPESTATUS` holds the results of the `a`, the `b`, the `c`, and the `d`, but not of the negation.  In my scenario (`grep a x && ! grep b y`, actually) this produced rather peculiar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`! a | b | c` is interpreted as `!{a | b | c;}` by the shell  & not as `{! a;} | b | c`.

Individual command exit statuses are stored in `${PIPESTATUS[@]}`.

The `$?` refers to exit-status of the entire command, including `!`.

You can force `(! a) | b | c` by actually spawning the subshell. e.g.

```
$ true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
$ (! true); echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1
$ false; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1
$ (! false); echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this behavior is *intended* and becomes clearer if viewed with a complete pipeline:

```
a | b | c | d ; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

This will show the exit statuses of the processes `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Negations, now, only apply to the exit status of a complete pipeline:

```
! a | b | c | d ; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

It is not allowed to negate parts of the pipeline:

```
a | ! b | c | d   # Syntax error at "| !"
```

Because of this approach, the pipe associates stronger than the negation (one can say that this is a `! (a | b | c | d)` on the association level), so the results of the pipe constituents are not affected by the negation because the negation is applied later, after evaluating the pipeline.